Does my new pc need to update bios or install windows
We resolved the issue :) thanks for the help 
I’ve check the Gigabyte supported CPUs, and this CPU needs to run on UEFI firmware F1, we are on F3; I should update that and then install Windows correct?

I helped a friend build a new PC and we are using the Ryzen 7 7800X3D with a Gigabyte B650 Gaming X AX V2
We have tried booting it a couple times to no avail, tried booting it on a FAT32 formatted thumb drive with multiple UEFI firmware versions, Windows 11, and both - it usually boots to a screen that says invalid BIOS image, but it sometimes boots to a screen that lets us select a drive to boot from, then starts boot looping

UEFI firmware used (have tried F5 and F32G)

What is the minimum firmware revision required for the processor you are attempting to install? If you system POSTs with the processor you shouldn’t have to update the firmware before you install Windows unless there is a specific problem you are attempting to solve y updating the firmware

Yeah it posts so I don’t it needs new bios, does the windows installer need to be plugged into the bios usb port in order to boot? And how do I boot that it’s been awhile haha

If there is no operating system and the drive has no partition, and secure Boot is enabled it should by default boot to the only bootable media that exists. Installing Windows is really easy, if necessary, there is a ton of information available

Maybe I am missing something, but I do not see Ryzen 7 5800X3D on list of supported CPUs.

Use the Windows 11 Media Creation Tool (Direct download link) to create your installation media -- that way you can be confident that the USB drive was prepared properly.  See if you can boot to the USB drive on a different computer.  Make sure that your BIOS settings are squared away (SecureBoot is enabled, etc).  If you're still having issues booting to the USB flash drive, maybe try a different USB port and/or flash drive if you have one.

@DavidAnderson -- OP updated their question and now state that they're using a Ryzen 7 7800X3D (rather than a Ryzen 7 5800X3D)-- which is listed on the CPU Support site.

If your processor requires F1 and you are running F3 then your firmware already supports the processor. Is your question about updating the firmware or installing Windows?

@ColeDobmeier Please don't edit the question with the answer, please post an answer as to what resolved the issue, then please mark it as the accepted answer =]
